# How do I request USA visa for brazilian people?

Tags: visas, usa, brazil, brazilian-citizens

How do Brazilian people (in Brazil) request a USA visa card to travel there?

Answer (score 8):

Step-by-step to request visa card to travel to USA:

> Source in portuguese: [Correio Brasiliense](http://www.correiobraziliense.com.br/app/noticia/turismo/2013/01/02/interna_turismo,342096/vai-viajar-para-os-eua-confira-o-passo-a-passo-para-tirar-o-visto.shtml)
>   USA embassy in Brazil: [USA embassy in Brazil](http://portuguese.brazil.usembassy.gov/)

1. The tourist must fill out the new online DS-160 to apply for a visa at the following address: https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/. Data must be entered in English, with photo, and the applicant chooses where do the interview (for example, anyone who goes to the Embassy, you must select Brasilia).
2. After receiving the confirmation, print the page (with barcode).
3. Pay the visa application fee (MRV). For tourists, the value is $ 160 (maybe  different value) and the payment can be made by bank transfer or credit card.
4. Schedule your interview by site http://brazil.usvisa-info.com through registration, stating the confirmation code of your DS-160, or by calling (61) 2626-6503 (maybe different), Monday through Friday, from 7 up to 19h. Applicants under 15 years old or over 66 years do not need to go through an interview.
5. In the scheduled date, attends a Service Center Visa Applicant (ASC) - in Brasilia in 2000 Venancio (SCS, Block 8, Block B) - which will be harvested your digital photo prints. It must take: valid passport, prior passports with valid visas or due and the confirmation page of the DS-160 form. (see http://portuguese.brazil.usembassy.gov/pt/additionaldocs.html).
6. The average time for delivery of the passport with the visa is 10 days after the interview. If after this period, the applicant does not receive the document, please send an email to entrevista.contactus_pt_br@usvisa.info.com or entrega@usvisa-info.com. You can also get the passport at the interview location (Embassy or Consulate) within five business days, at the scheduled time.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you, but some people dislike people who answer their own questions, even though they should not: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @jpatokal this has happened to me on other sites of the network, and it is very annoying when the downvote is not explained